# how to add bundle products in cart without specify options

Tags: product-view, bundle

I created the bundle product and have two options but i want customer can add bundle products without specify options. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

You may only add a bundle product to the cart under the following conditions:

- The options are marked as "not required"
- Required options have defaults
- User defined quantities start with a default quantity of 1

Otherwise there'd be nothing to add!

Hope that helps.

Comment: i want only bundle product is added to cart without selected any options

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific.

Comment: Not possible. as per standard we have to select at least 1 option from all the bundle options. Otherwise, products will not be added. Do you want to do like this, then It's better to go with simple product with custom options.

Answer (score 0):

Not Possible. Bundle Options required at least 1 option to be selected.